# What can be the cause of some strange ray shadows artefacts on a perfectly flat surface?

Tags: raytracing, shadow, artifacts

First of all I have to say that I am really new in the world of Computer Graphics. I apologise if some of my questions may appear trivial.
I am currently using a non-commercial ray tracing and physically based rendering software. I didn't have any problems with this until now : I have a scene where an .obj file representing a satellite is placed surrounded by a environment map light.
Here is an exemple of my problem appearing on the solar pannels :

[image]

I have no idea where these strange forms could come from. I have to say that for this picture, the .obj file representating the solar pannel is a very simple parallelepiped. I also tried to suppress the other face of the object but nothing changed.

I saw this exchange ([Cause of shadow acne](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/cause-of-shadow-acne)) that could maybe be related to my problem, but if someone has an idea of what could be the cause, I would be happy to hear it!

Thank you to all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that it was exactly the problem explained in the link of my original post ([Cause of shadow acne](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/cause-of-shadow-acne)).
The shadow function offset has been increased and the problem is solved!